# How to prevent web socket DDOS attacks?

Tags: php, nginx, ratchet, socketrocket

I just performed a basic DDOS from my computer:

```
websocket-bench -a 2500 -c 200 wss://s.example.com
```

Which to my total dismay crashed my server! The WS works by connecting to my nginx proxy:

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://sock;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
            proxy_read_timeout 60;
    }

    upstream sock {
            server 127.0.0.1:1203 fail_timeout=1s;
    }
```

and locally on the server on port `1203` is [ratchet](http://socketo.me/). The setup for ratchet is that I allow any connection and the first `onMessage` performs authentication and if invalid the connection is closed.

I also have tried authentication by passing headers on the first connection and if invalid the socket closes but this has not helped at all and nginx still reaches 100% resources and then crashes.

What should I be analysing to prevent these crashes?

When changing the upstream to another closed port (i.e disabling it) the server still crashes.

Comment: You can't prevent DDOS by "tweaking" some config variables or installing a program that prevens it. Your problem isn't the ddos, it's the fact that once crashed - service doesn't come back up. That's why we use `supervisord`. Also, using nodejs instead of ratchet would yield significant gains.

Comment: Yeah but the point of my question is that a DDOS is caused when it shouldn't be. My network with 6mb/s upload shouldn't be able to crash a gigabit server with requests - meaning there is something wrong with my config.

Comment: If 10,000 people reached my http web server now it would just slow down the server not crash it.

Comment: 10k for nginx and node wouldn't be a problem. You'd use services like Cloudflare to prevent it. If you *need* 10k people connected, you use multiple nginx instances (your DNS points to multiple IP addresses that handle your domain) and each nginx load balances to several ratchet/nodejs instances that handle web sockets. That's how scaling is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change your authentication logic so Nginx handles it, or implement [request and connection limits](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) within Nginx to control how many connections are accepted and passed to the upstream server

Comment: limits does not seem to affect anything unfortunately. I can't quite believe that it is nginx crashing my server! I am worried that it may be my ratchet php script.

Comment: Hmm, ok. What happens if you remove your upstream block altogether and change your proxypass directive to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1203` ? You normally use an upstream directive to define a group of servers, if your ratchet instance fails then `fail_timeout=1s` will make Nginx mark the server as down for 10 seconds. Usually it would route requests to other servers in the upstream block, but you dont have any. Personally though I would recommend the Nchan websocket module for Nginx, works a treat.